# Issue in the Assets folder

Tags: android, file, fonts, assets

I had an issue where a font didnt work and it gave me a FC. So I put the font file into the sdcard, and used CreateFromFile in the typeface and the font worked!
Here is the code I used for the Assets folder:

```
        holder.tv_SuraName   =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Start_Name);
    holder.tv_SuraName.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "suralist_font.ttf"));
```

But I changed the code to this and it worked:

```
            holder.tv_SuraName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Start_Name);
        Typeface Font = Typeface.createFromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/asd.ttf"));
```

Does this mean I have a problem in the Assets folder? How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: In your code in which you are creating font from file you had not set typeface to textview are you setting typeface on textview sure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this

```
  Typeface font0 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/AmericanDream.ttf"); 
  tv1.setTypeface(font0);
```

here fonts (folder in assets) folder containing AmericanDream.ttf file inside.
like:assets-->fonts-->AmericanDream.ttf
i hope this will help u.

Comment: This worked.. its odd but now it works.. Is it better to get the font from the Assets or from the File?

Answer (score 0):

```
AssetManager assetManager1 = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager1, "James_Fajardo.ttf");
```

and used in textview like

```
urTextView.setTypeface(tf1, Typeface.BOLD);
```

hope useful for u.

Comment: Please make sure you have put your "suralist_font.ttf" file in assets folder because if file not exist in assets than only give an error like "native facetype cannot be made". i'hv tried this.

Comment: I do have that file there :( Well I guess I will continue with getting the font  from file